# How to restore a deleted component in RTC source control

Tags: clearcase, rtc

Is it possible to restore a deleted component ?

I have created a snapshot of my stream and can view the deleted component by viewing the snapshot. Is it possible to re-add the component to a stream from a snapshot ?
Or is there another method of restoring a component ?

(as opposed to ClearCase, where I had to rebase an UCM stream with a component baseline)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by deleted you mean removed from your disk, you can simply reload your repo workspace into your local workspace (or sandbox).
Note: a local workspace or sandbox is the same than a ClearCase snapshot view, but you wouldn't call it "snapshot".
In RTC, a snapshot is a global label which included all component latests on a stream.

If by deleted, you mean removed from your repository workspace, yes, you can add it back (it is still in the Stream), and click on save.

If by deleted, you mean removed from the Stream itself, you can add it back at the Stream level (open that stream, and in the "Component" section, click on "Add").
If it is still in your repo workspace, you can then deliver it back to the stream.

The OP adds:

> I mean "removed from the Stream itself" so if the component is also removed from my repo workspace, it cannot be restored from a snapshot?

Yes, it can be restore from a snapshot:

> I could:
>
> - create a new workspace from the snapshot,
> - update my flowtarget to be this newly created repo and accept the component from here.
> - Then update the flow target to be stream where component was removed and
> - deliver the component to stream.

I confirm this should work.
And you can indeed create a repo workspace from a snapshot: that is what enable a user to quickly debug a Build Record with a "failed build" status: each build first put a snapshot on the cond on which they will operate.

Comment: I mean "removed from the Stream itself" so if the component is also removed from my repo workspace, it cannot be restored from a snapshot ? I could create a new workspace from the snapshot, update my flowtarget to be this newly created repo and accept the component from here. Then update the flow target to be stream where component was removed and deliver the component to stream.

Comment: @user470184 your method for restoring the component seems sound, and I have included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If deleted from the Stream itself, you can add it back at the Stream level (Open that stream, and in the "Component" section, click on "Add" either from a baseline or snapshot, you can search for it if you remember the full or partial component name). Save the stream finally.